# Insertion Sort crashing my program

Tags: c++

I'm building a program where the user inputs numbers up to 100 times, and finishing by entering a negative integer. The program is supposed to sort the numbers and display them back to the user. Right now my program crashes when it gets to the sorting loop and I am not sure why.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(char nums[], int count)
{

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
        for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
            cout << " " << nums[j];
    cout << endl;
}

void Sort(char nums[], int count)
{
    int i, j, tmp;

    for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (nums[j - 1] > nums[j]) {
            tmp = nums[j];
            nums[j] = nums[j - 1];
            nums[j - 1] = tmp;
            j--;
        } //end of while loop
        print(nums, count);
    } //end of for loop
}

int main()
{
    char nums[101];
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Please enter between 2 and 100 intgers, ending with a negative                                                    integer.\nThe Negative will not be included in the list;\n";

    for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++) {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        if (temp < 0) {

            break;
        }
        nums[count] = temp;
        count++;
    }
    nums[count + 1] = '\0';

    Sort(nums, count);
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger and step through your code line by line and watch variables changing. That will most probably lead you to solve your problem.

Comment: Why read it as an int an put it in a char[]?

Comment: You increment the internal `count` variable in the `for` loop twice. Rename from `int count` in the `for` loop to something else. Even `i` works better.

Answer (score 0):

At least one issue is you are using the wrong `count`.  In

```
for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++) {
    int temp;
    cin >> temp;
    if (temp < 0) {

        break;
    }
    nums[count] = temp;
    count++;
}
```

The `count` you are using is the `count` declared in the for loop.  You then use the `count` you declared in main when you do

```
nums[count + 1] = '\0';

Sort(nums, count);
```

which is still `0`.

You are also going to have an issue with

```
while (nums[j - 1] > nums[j]) {
    tmp = nums[j];
    nums[j] = nums[j - 1];
    nums[j - 1] = tmp;
    j--;
}
```

As you never check if `j < 1`.  If `j < 1` then you have a negative index which is undefined behavior.